# RegExp - найти набор однотипных строк, между которых может быть произвольная строка

Tags: регулярные-выражения, postgresql

С помощью регулярных выражений PosgreSQL нужно определить, есть ли в тексте фиксированное количество пронумерованных строк (не больше и не меньше), начинающихся на определенную последовательность. Например, есть ли в тексте ровно 6 одинаковых строк, начинающихся на число + //:

```
texttexttext

1// texttexttext
2// texttexttext
3// texttexttext
4// texttexttext
5// texttexttext
6// texttexttext
texttexttext
texttexttext
texttexttext
texttexttext
```

Сейчас ищу таким выражением:

```
(\n[1-6][//|\\|.| |)][^\n]+){6}\n(\D[^\n]+\n)*((?!7))
```

Но оно не срабатывает, если между пронумерованными строками есть произвольные строки:

```
texttexttext

1// texttexttext
2// texttexttext
3// texttexttext
texttexttext
texttexttext
4// texttexttext
5// texttexttext
6// texttexttext
texttexttext
texttexttext
texttexttext
texttexttext
```

Таких строк в середине может быть от 1 до 3 подряд, эта последовательность может быть только 1 раз. Есть ли возможность учесть эту ситуацию в регулярном выражении?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете просто выбрать строчки, где число совпадений равно 6.  Это
можно сделать с помощью комбинации функции `regexp_matches`
и *бокового перекрёстного соединения* (англ. «*lateral cross
join*»).  Пример:

```sql
SELECT t.id
  FROM t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL
         regexp_matches(t.a, '^a', 'gn')
       AS u(m)
 GROUP BY t.id
HAVING COUNT(u.m) = 3
;
```

Данный запрос выведет *ID* строчки из таблицы `t`, где
текст (колонка `a`) содержит ровно три строчки, начинающихся
с латинской буквы `a`.